# Check the convergence of this sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$a_1=5^{1/k}$ , $a_{n+1}=(5a_{n})^{1/k}$
Check the convergence of this sequence.
I already proved that it is monotonically increasing but i could not prove that it is bounded. please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one looks at the first few members of the sequence one gets:

$$a_1 = 5^{1/k}$$
$$a_2 = (5 \cdot 5^{1/k})^{1/k} = 5^{1/k(1/k + 1)} = 5^{(1/k)^2 + 1/k}$$
$$a_3 = (5 \cdot 5^{1/k^2 + 1/k})^{1/k} = 5^{1/k((1/k)^2 + 1/k+1)} = 5^{(1/k)^3 + (1/k)^2 + 1/k}$$

Per induction one gets in general $a_n = 5^{(\sum_{j=1}^n (1/k)^j)}$.

This converges exactly then, if $\sum_{j=1}^\infty (1/k)^j$ does. That is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) and hence converges for $|1/k| < 1$ towards $\tfrac{1}{1-(1/k)}$. In that case the sequence converges towards $5^{\tfrac{1}{1-(1/k)}}$.